# SerializeObject throws System.OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a serious problem with "JsonConvert.SerializeObject" I need to serialize more than 500,000 dictionary records to make serialize throws the following error; System.OutOfMemoryException. I tried to serialize each key, value pair individually in a foreach but it's locked. Apparently it is an optimization problem, but I do not know where to start, threads to serialize in parts?
These functions works fine with few values. 
My code:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DatatableToDictionary(dt), Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);

public List<Dictionary<string, object>> DatatableToDictionary(DataTable dt, List<DataColumn> columns)
{
    return dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(
         r => columns.ToDictionary(c => c.ColumnName, c => r[c.ColumnName])).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you need to restore to `JsonWriter` instead.

Comment: Culprit can be circular references as well

Comment: Most likely the total size of the json string to create is too big. Can you show the structure of your dictionary and surrounding types? I was able to easily and quickly write out a million dictionary keys with values to a json file using a stream, a StreamWriter and the JsonTextWriter.

Comment: Excuse me but how can restore jsonWriter and know if there are circular references?

Answer (score 5):

When you're dealing with a large amount of data, you can stream it to a file to avoid having it all in memory at once.

```
var filePath = @"C:\somewhere.json";

using (var fs = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.CreateNew))
using (var sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
using (var jw = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
{
    var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    serializer.Serialize(jw, dictionary);
}
```

This will serialize a bit at a time and avoid having a giant string in memory.

Comment: Yes it works fine,I guess then I have to read the file to retrieve the data? because it is a web api, as I'm doing for an MVC application. Is there any way to store information in cache and not in any path?

Comment: Yes, then you read the file to get data. Reading it is basically the reverse process. The file can basically act as your cache.