# Owin WebApi Post method with Large Object

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, out-of-memory, owin, dotnet-httpclient

I am using OWIN to self-host a Web API 2 windows service. It works well most of the time, except for large custom objects which cause an OutOfMemoryException on the client end (winforms app).

**QUESTION: How do I POST a large custom object?**

The OutOfMemoryException initially happened at the end of this piece of code at `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

static HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();  

public async Task SaveMyObjectAsync(MyObject largeObject)
{
    var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync("myobjects/route/", new JsonContent(largeObject));
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
}

public static class JsonSettings
{
    public static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Default =
    new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver(),
        NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
        ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize,
        DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.RoundtripKind,
        DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.DateTimeOffset,
        DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat,
        Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
        Converters = new List<JsonConverter>
        {
            new StringEnumConverter(),
        }
    };
}

public class JsonContent : StringContent
{
    public JsonContent(object value) : base(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value, JsonSettings.Default), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json") {}
}
```

### First Attempt

So from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39598469/345659) I swapped out the serialize method to write to local file instead. This worked for a while until I realised that it had just increased the size limit it could handle. I was still getting an OutOfMemoryException with larger objects but now it was on `File.ReadAllText`

```
public JsonContent(object value) : base(SerializeObjectByStream(value), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json") { }

static string SerializeObjectByStream(object value)
{
    using (TextWriter textWriter = File.CreateText("LocalJsonFile.json"))
    {
        JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => JsonSettings.Default;
        using (var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(textWriter))
        {
            var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            serializer.Serialize(jsonWriter, value);
            jsonWriter.Flush();
        }
    }
    return File.ReadAllText("LocalJsonFile.json");
}
```

### Multipart Attempt

Sending objects this large in a single part are probably a bad idea anyway, so I tried using `MultipartContent` to break it up. Most of the examples seemed to cover reading multipart requests, rather than creating it, but this code works for my regular size custom objects. Unfortunately it STILL throws an OutOfMemoryException for large objects. This time it is internal to the Newtonsoft JsonSerializer at `ser.Serialize(jsonWriter, request)`.

I also tried using a FileStream instead of a MemoryStream with the same problem. This time the OutOfMemoryException was at `_httpClient.PostAsync`

```
using (var content = new MultipartContent())
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
        JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => JsonSettings.Default;
        var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(writer);
        var ser = new JsonSerializer();
        ser.Serialize(jsonWriter, request);
        jsonWriter.Flush();
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        content.Add(new StreamContent(stream));

        var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync("myobjects/route/", content);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    }
}
```

It seems all I am doing is pushing around this data to get an Out of Memory problem in a different place.
How do I break this large custom object down into chunks - while keeping it in 1 transaction????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that was a lot less intuitive than I thought. This code seems to perform quite well (cancellationtokens, etc removed for simplicity). Although I am somewhat concerned about using a generic filename for my FileStream. Being async I suppose it is possible 2 instances might try to create the same file at the same time?

It was quite painful switching from the `JsonSerializer` to the `BinaryFormatter`, as it meant I had to go through and decorate all of my classes with the `[Serializable]` attribute. I was also relying on the behaviour of the JsonSerializer to use the default constructors, [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11946658/345659), which was converting my nulls to empty strings for me.

**Client:**

```
const int MaximumChunkSize = 1024000;

public async Task SaveMyObjectAsync(MyObject largeObject)
{
    //use fileStream to write the object to disk, 
    // so it does not hold it all in memory at the same time
    using (var stream = new FileStream("LocalStreamFile.json", FileMode.Create))
    {
        //JsonSerializer unable to serialize a large object 
        // without OOM error, so use BinaryFormatter
        var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        formatter.Serialize(stream, request);
        //return to the start of the stream
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        using (var content = new MultipartContent())
        {
            var buffer = new byte[MaximumChunkSize];
            while (stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length) > 0)
            {
                //add the large object in chunks to the multipart content
                content.Add(new JsonContent(buffer));
            }
            var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync("myobjects/route/", content);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        }
    }
}
```

**Server:**

```
[HttpPost, Route("myobjects/route/")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> SaveMyObjectAsync()
{
    if (Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent() == false)
    {
        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    var contentStreamProvider = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync();
    var stream = new FileStream("LocalStreamFile.json", FileMode.Create);
    foreach (var content in contentStreamProvider.Contents)
    {
        //read out the chunk and convert from json
        var requestArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<byte[]>(await content.ReadAsStringAsync(), JsonSettings.Default);
        stream.Write(requestArray, 0, requestArray.Length);
    }
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    //convert back from stream to our original large object
    var request = (MyObject)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
    //save to database etc
    ...
    return Ok();
}
```